# AngularJS regular expression for number and comma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

my input field must accept the follwoing number, space, comma and dot

five of example below can be only accepted

1) 50,000.00
2) 50 000,00
3) 50000.00
4) 50 000
5) 50000

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? People are a lot more likely to help and not downvote if you provide code that you've tried yourself.

Comment: What is your code, and where does it fail? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Jason Please post your code. Cannot help without.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9\s,\.]*$" />
```

Check the below [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LRb9oe4wOsMMgD6W8jAR?p=preview)